# Plot a Subset as Data Labels in Multi-Plot Loop

Tags: r, plot

What I'm trying to do is create a loop to plot all of my Project Manager's projects based on contract size and profit (Variance). I'm then attempting to draw an `abline()` between the points to determine what their profit might be on future projects. Finally, I would like to label all points at a certain criteria (`Contract >=500000 & Status =="A"`).

I have figured out most of it so far but can't seem to figure out how to subset my data using the `text()` function. Instead, what I end up with is a plot with all the labels instead of a specific few.

Here is my data frame:

```
data <- data.frame(Project.Manager=c("Bert", "Ernie" ,"Elmo","Bert", "Ernie" ,"Elmo","Bert","Ernie","Elmo"),
               Contract=c(100000,15000,25000,588000,1250000,355000,50000,80000,335000),
               Variance=c(15000,-50000,2000,100000,550000,-180000,-15000,25000,100000),
               Project=c("Bert's House", "Ernie's House", "Elmo's House", "Oscar Trash Can Renovations", "Big Bird's Nest", "Sesame St. Renovations","Count's Corner","Tickle Me Elmo Factory", "Set Production"),
               Status=c("A","C","C","C","A","C","C","C","C"))

data$Color <- "black"
data$Color[data$Status =="A"]<-"green"
```

And here is my code so far for a 3x1 plot.

```
par(mar=c(2,4,2,1))
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
par(cex=0.6)
xrange <- c(0,1500000)
ticks2 <- pretty(xrange)
labels2 <- format(ticks2, big.mark=",", scientific = FALSE)
yrange <- c(-200000,600000)
ticks <- pretty(yrange)
labels <- format(ticks, big.mark=",",scientific=FALSE)
pos_vector <- rep(4, length(data$Project))

by (data,data$Project.Manager,function(i){
  plot(i$Contract,i$Variance,main=unique(i$Project.Manager),yaxt="n",ylim=yrange,
  xaxt="n",xlim=xrange,xlab="Profit",ylab="",col=i$Color)
  with(data,text(i$Contract,i$Variance,labels=i$Project,cex=0.7,pos=pos_vector))
  axis(2, at =ticks,labels=labels,las=1,cex.axis=0.7)
  axis(1, at = ticks2,labels=labels2,las=1,cex.axis=0.7)
  abline(0,0,col="red")
  abline(lm(i$Variance~i$Contract,subset = i$Status =="C"),col="blue",lty=2)
})
```

As it stands, here is my plot. Ideally, I would like only "Big Bird's House" to show up as a data label with the given criteria.
[image]